# Select count, how to retrieve all results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get all PARENT entries along with their children count.

For a single entry:

```
SELECT parent, COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE parent = 9
```

I'm trying to write a query that will go over all PARENTs:

```
SELECT parent, COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE parent IN table1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want count of all children by parent then you need to group by parent

`SELECT parent, COUNT(id) FROM table1 group by parent`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT parent, COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE parent IN (select parent from table1)
```

Comment: It only returned first parent ID and the count of the whole table